# Add meta data to a data lake file using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Azure Data Factory v2 has a Get Metadata activity which can read meta data on the files stored in ADLS. It can preserve the meta data on files when it moves/copies the files.
But is there a way to add or modify meta data on the lake files using ADF?

Comment: Which type of the meta data you want to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's a way.

You can make use of Azure Blob Storage API:

[set-blob-metadata method for Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata)

Data lake is just an extension to underlying Blob Storage engine

So, you can hook up a web activity in your pipeline and call the rest api pointing at your blob and it will set metadata for you.

Answer (score 1):

The meta data are created by Data Lake(Storage) once the files are uploaded on.

These properties can not be changed unless you delete and re-upload them to Data Lake(or Stroage). Some others have asked the same questions about how to change this meta data in Stack overflow. You could easily find these by seraching.

**But if you modify the content of the file in Data Lake, such as add or delete columns, the `size`, `columnCount` and `structure` can be changed.**

So for the question "is there a way to add or modify meta data on the lake files using ADF?", the answer is no, there isn't.

HTP.

Comment: I disagree. We can change meta data on a blob using something like Storage explorer even after they have been created  w/o deleting.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi  I can understan you. Off course you could add the meta data in the Storage explorer. But the output(Metadata) of Get Metadata is different with the blob metadata. They are different things.

Comment: Data Factory is more like get the properties of the file. We can not change it in Data Factory. You could test add some metadata in Storage explorer and then use Get meta data to get them.